# Ticket to Ride United Kingdom, should the technology cards be in a stack or do we get to choose?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-united-kingdom

I find the rules very unclear in how the technology cards should be used. It is not mentioned that they should be in a stack with which players get to buy the card on top of the stack.

But it is neither explicitly said that the technology cards may be bought of our choosing. I figured that there are so many it may become a complex and players would have to commit the different cards to memory before being able to play the game.

So do we get to buy those tech cards we want, or are we depended on whatever the stack pops up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As further evidence all cards are on display,  This image is taken from the official app where for U.K. map the tech cards are all displayed and the player can select any they can pay for.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I think the rules are clear enough by the use of "Available" when listing the Technologies and the absence of any description of a restriction on them. But the question has come up before, so it certainly could be clearer.

The designer [responded](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1501432/article/21392653#21392653) to one of those instances in 2016:

> All tech cards are available from game start.
>
> Most tech cards last until game end, but a few (e.g., Right of Way) must be discarded to have effect. They go back to the available tech card display for repurchase later in the game.

Answer (score 5):

When playing Ticket to Ride UK, the technology cards should be in different stacks based on the technologies themselves, not in one stack with all the technologies. They are not like the train cards, where you can only take blinds or what is in the row. As long as the technologies are not exhausted, you can buy whichever one you choose.